# CodeIgniter can't read any POST

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Whatever/however i post via HTML Form in CodeIgniter- my `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` array is empty. However, when method is set to `get`, everything looks fine.

I know my issue is with Apache / .htaccess Or URI settings. I'm running XAMPP on Windows 7.

```
<form method='post' action='auth/login'>
    <input type='submit' name='login' value='TEST' />
</form>
```

Now in controller `auth` function `login` should return me

```
Array( 'login' => 'TEST' );
```

What i'm getting is

```
Array( );
```

What have i allready tried to make it read the `$_POST`?

- I have tried setting my **ALL** `uri_protocol` settings.
- Tried the CodeIgniter config `index_page` on `''` and `'index.php'`
- Tried a lot of different .htaccess methods.
- Checked that my apache `mod_rewrite` is included/allowed, and it  is.
- Checked that allow rewrite is set to `All` everywhere it can in apache/conf/httpd.conf
- Tried to read the `$_POST` with `$this->input->post()`
- Made the action path absolute, still nothing.
- Tried to post from external script to CodeIgniter index.php

Everything results with nothing. And i know problem must be with Apache settings cause all other *folders/projects* without .htaccess work perfectly.

So here are exact .htaccess contents i have tried, which worked the best 4me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] # returns 404 everywhere.

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]  # Pages work good!
```

^^ This worked the best (at least i got webpage running) but not the `$_POST`.

For thous who want to see **controller**(auth.php) code:

```
class auth extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        # Parent constructor.
        parent::__construct();
    }    

    function login() {
        # Trying to read post
        print_r($_POST);
        print_r($this->input->post());

        # Loading form.
        $this->load->view('login_page');
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use form_open('auth/login') CI form helper method or <form method='post' action='<?=site_url('auth/login')?>'> and check

Comment: For post there is no need to any htaccess or removeing index.php this is for preety urls

Comment: @umefarooq I tried your solution right now, it ended up making absolute path in `action` which is http://localhost/auth/login, and i'm still getting no results.

Comment: post you controller code too

Comment: @RakeshSharma I did now, you want to look at updated Question now :)

Comment: looks all ok try to change `function` to `public function` and form action your full url

Comment: Now i made it `public function login() {` results are the same =( no `$_POST`. Thank you @RakeshSharma that you reply that often and quick, i am stuck on that problem for 3 days now and that's why made this question, really hope someone/you can help me solve it :)!

Comment: do a inspect element on form and your action must be`http://localhost/yoursite/index.php/auth/login` and also add some more input to post and check

Comment: what is your CI version

Comment: My CodeIgniter version is 2.2.1, I added 2 inputs user and pass with names  and values of course.  In my path i really don't have `/yoursite/` part cause my index.php is right in the htdocs folder. My action allready was fullpath and now it is just controller/function both methods result the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is the solution in my case:

I made an overwrite to CI_Model to always check if there is `$this->input->post('login')` and if so, check if posted user & pass validates. If it does not validate `redirect` to login page. And that `redirect` was clearing all my post.

Thanks to everybody that tried to help, i apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Try This remove your action and add enctype

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='submit' name='login' value='TEST' />
</form>
```

and in your controller

add below code in current action.

```
 if($this->input->post()){
    echo "<pre>";print_r($this->input->post());die;
    }
```

Comment: I just did exactly as you asked. I Don't see any `<pre>` tag in HTML code when i view the source code so i suggest that `if($this->input->post()){` didn't trigger. I'm sure the issue is in something that is routing my `$_POST` in the server itself (on my local machine) cause on virtual hosts/servers on the web no-one has had that issue (when i google'd that only local ones had that problem without solution)